# How can I trigger a rebuild of my Android apk?

Tags: android

I have an apk that is built with make, and so it has an Android.mk file associated with it. Now, I want to make sure that this apk is rebuilt every time a specific file (that is not related to the apk at all) has changed. So I need to somehow specify a dependency from my apk to this specific file but I can't figure out how to do that. Any advice?

Any input is appreciated!

Thank you!

Some more information:

The problem that I am seeing is that the Android.mk files for apk:s don't have any "targets" in them. They basically just look something like  this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := MyApp

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```

Since there is no target, I cannot add any dependency.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `make` and not `ant`, then make files usually have a format

```
<target> : <dependencies>
<tab><command>
```

If that's what your Android.mk tends to look like, then I would say just add the name of this other file to the dependency list.

If I'm totally off here, can we see part or all of Android.mk?